# Mongoose query returning undefined in console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

the following code is part of my router code:

```
.get(function(req, res) {

    var project = Project.findOne({ 'projectName': req.params.id }, function (err, project) {

        if (err) return handleError(err);

    }); 

    console.log('found project: ' + project.projectName);
```

However, the code above returns 'undefined' on the server side. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you just console.log('project'); is that undefined?

Comment: It's because `findOne()` is asynchronous, put the `console.log('found project: ' + project.projectName);` inside the callback, after the `handleError(err)` line.